# Need assistance debugging my python code, it's a wreck

Tags: python, debugging

I'm using Python 2.7x and am having trouble debugging it. I'm not really sure what I can do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import re
import sys

# Grab parameters from the command line
(filename, threshold) = sys.argv[1:3]

# Validate arguments
if (re.match("\D", threshold)):
   print "The threshold must be a number."
   sys.exit(1)

# Read file and tally word frequencies
fh = open(filename)
file = fh.read()
words = []
for line in file.split('\n'):
   found = 0
   for word in words:
      if word[0] == line.lower():
         found = 1
         word[1] += 1

   # initialize a new word with a frequency of 1
   if found == 0:
      words.append([line, 1])

# Print words and their frequencies, sorted alphabetically by word.  Only print a word if its frequency is greater than or equal to the threshold.
for word in sorted(words):
   if word[0] < threshold: continue
   print "%4d %s" % (word[1], word[0])
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some information about what isn't working.

Comment: Define "having trouble debugging it."  Are you running into specific issues with a debugger?  What isn't working?

Comment: Don't think this should have been closed - question was posed poorly, but is valid none the same. @user1100031, if I had to guess, I'd say that your issue is that you never add anything to the word list - it starts off empty, so you never enter the `for word in words` loop.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - closed does not mean deleted, if the question is edited to make it clearer wat is being asked e.g. by showing info requested in the other comments then it could be reopened

Answer (score 2):

In general, debugging Python code is easiest with the `pdb` module. Place the following code where you want the debugger to start:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

You can use `n` to execute the next line of code, `s` to step into functions, and `p` to print a value (e.g., `p words` will print your words list).

I can't really know what's going on with your code without more information on the problem, but it appears you might be having an issue with inconsistent cases. When you add something to the word list, you should put it in lower case.

```
if found == 0:
    words.append([line.lower(), 1])
```

Also, you're comparing a string to the threshold, not a number. It should be:

```
if word[1] < threshold: continue
```

I hope this helps.